# How can I stop my script going out of range?

Tags: python

As I was bored and wanted to practice my python, I thought I'd write a script that took some genetic code and converted it into the amino acid sequence. It looks through the code one letter at a time and when it sees a certain sequence, starts translating triplets of genetic code into their equivalent amino acid and strings them together until it reaches a triplet of genetic code that doesn't encode an amino acid. The script then goes back to where it started this translation, and restarts iterating through the code until it finds another start sequence.

The script works, up to a point. I started off using a while loop to iterate through the triplets of genetic code after a start sequence, but when it reaches the end of the genetic code, it goes out of range:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

def main():
    translation = {'gca':'A', 'gcc':'A', 'gcg':'A', 'gct':'A', 'tgc':'C', 'tgt':'C', 'gac':'D', 'gat':'D', 'gaa':'E', 'gag':'E', 'ttc':'F', 'ttt':'F', 'gga':'G', 'ggg':'G', 'ggc':'G', 'ggt':'G', 'cac':'H', 'cat':'H', 'ata':'I', 'atc':'I', 'att':'I', 'aaa':'K', 'aag':'K', 'tta':'L', 'ttg':'L', 'cta':'L', 'ctc':'L', 'ctg':'L', 'ctt':'L', 'atg':'M', 'tgg':'W', 'tac':'Y', 'tat':'Y'}
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['aac', 'aat'], 'N'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['cca', 'ccc', 'ccg', 'cct'], 'P'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['caa', 'cag'], 'Q'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['aac', 'aat'], 'N'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['aga', 'agg', 'cga', 'cgc', 'cgg', 'cgt'], 'R'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['agc', 'agt', 'tca', 'tcc', 'tcg', 'tct'], 'S'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['aca', 'acc', 'acg', 'act'], 'T'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['gta', 'gtc', 'gtg', 'gtt'], 'V'))
    translation.update(dict.fromkeys(['taa', 'tga', 'tag'], 'STOP'))
    
    rna = ""
    f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') #gets the code from a file
    for line in f:
        trimmedline = re.sub(r'[^atcgu]','', line)
        rna = rna + trimmedline
        
    f.close()
    
    #This part of the code iterates through the rna string one letter at a time
    #At each letter it grabs the next two letters in the string and joins the three letters together -> codon
    #If the codon pattern matches one of two strings it grabs the corresponding value from the translation dict and adds this to the 'primary' string
    #It then triggers a while loop that moves through the rna string, pulling back triplets and looking them up in the translation dict
    #These values are also added to primary
    #When the while loop returns 'STOP', the while loop exits and the for loop begins the process again from the next letter in 'rna'
    #i.e. if the first 'a' in atgcaaca... triggered the while loop, the next letter would be t
    for base in range(len(rna) - 2):
        codon = rna[base] + rna[base + 1] + rna[base + 2]
        if (codon == 'aug' or codon == "atg"):
            print 'Start codon found at position ' + str(base)
            primary = translation[codon]
            reset = 0
            l = 1
            while reset == 0:
                newcodon = rna[base + (3 * l)] + rna[base + (3 * l) + 1] + rna[base + (3 * l) + 2]
                if translation[newcodon] == 'STOP':
                    reset = 1
                    print primary
                    print '------------'
                else:
                    primary = primary + translation[newcodon]
                    #print primary
                    l = l + 1            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can't figure out how to stop the script from running over the end of the genetic sequence. I tried using another for loop in place of the while loop, but I kept on getting an error: string indices must be integers, not str.

```
            for triplet in rna[base + 3:((len(rna)-base)-((len(rna)- base) % 3)): 3]:
                newcodon = rna[triplet] + rna[triplet + 1] + rna[triplet + 2]
#                newcodon = rna[base + (3 * l)] + rna[base + (3 * l) + 1] + rna[base + (3 * l) + 2]
                if translation[newcodon] == 'STOP':
                    reset = 1
                    print primary
                    print '------------'
                else:
                    primary = primary + translation[newcodon]
                    l = l + 1
```

Can anyone help put me out of my misery?

If you want/need some sample data you can use:

```
29581 ttttccgttt acgatatata gtctactctt gtgcagaatg aattctcgta actacatagc
29641 acaagtagat gtagttaact ttaatctcac atagcaatct ttaatcagtg tgtaacatta
29701 gggaggactt gaaagagcca ccacattttc accgaggcca cgcggagtac gatcgagtgt
29761 acagtgaaca atgctaggga gagctgccta tatggaagag ccctaatgtg taaaattaat
29821 tttagtagtg ctatccccat gtgattttaa tagcttctta ggagaatgac aaaaaaaaaa
29881 aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa
```

(Part of SARS-CoV-2 if you're interested)

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace of the error message that you get. It is really hard for someone unfamiliar with the code to work out where in the 52 lines of your code the range error might arise. Please edit your question to include *the full stack trace of the error that you get*.

Comment: Unrelated but, note that it looks like you're using `reset` as a boolean, but you're writing `1` and `0` instead of `True` and `False`. I'm also curious about your python version: based on your print statements it is some python 2 version which is incredibly outdated.

Comment: Thanks @Kraigolas, I tried using 'true' and 'false' but it wasn't working; now I see it I should have capitalised them. And yep, guilty as charged. I'm using Python 2.something - maybe I should try and teach myself Python 3 while I'm at it.

Comment: @BoarGules, thanks for the advice. Cameron seems to have solved it, but I'll note your point for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep incrementing `base` and incrementing `l` but without checking if you've exceeded the length of the rna string.  Changing the condition of your while loop to

```
while reset == 0 and len(rna) > (base + (3 * l) + 2):
```

will prevent the script from overrunning the length of the string.  (`base + (3 * l) + 2` is the largest index you attempt to add from the rna string, hence using it as the test to exit the while loop)